# Doubt regarding definition of pixel bond

Tags: image-processing, reference-request

The following is a quotation from [an Image processing textbook](https://www.worldcat.org/title/introduction-to-digital-image-processing/oclc/889321793&referer=brief_results):

The connectivity relationship between a center pixel and its eight neighbors can be quantified by the concept of a **pixel bond**, *the sum of the bond weights between the center pixel and each of its neighbors.* Each four-connected neighbor has a bond of two, and each eight-connected neighbor has a bond of one.

I am searching different sources to understand what is pixel bond. How four-connected neighbor has two and eight connected has one.

What exactly is the bond weight?

(The passage from this book seems to also be available via [Google Books](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=eoTSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA376&lpg=PA376&dq=The+connectivity+relationship+between+a+center+pixel+and+its+eight+neighbors+can+be+quantified+by+the+concept+of+a+pixel+bond,+the+sum+of+the+bond+weights+between+the+center+pixel+and+each+of+its+neighbors.+Each+four-connected+neighbor+has+a+bond+of+two,+and+each+eight-connected+neighbor+has+a+bond+of+one.&source=bl&ots=LJ5C_5-wFe&sig=qGjXNMpKBhK4xNT49wtN4I_G754&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikj7_Vh7LaAhUN448KHerzBVoQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Comment: Can you please provide a reference to that book?

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=eoTSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA376&lpg=PA376&dq=The+connectivity+relationship+between+a+center+pixel+and+its+eight+neighbors+can+be+quantified+by+the+concept+of+a+pixel+bond,+the+sum+of+the+bond+weights+between+the+center+pixel+and+each+of+its+neighbors.+Each+four-connected+neighbor+has+a+bond+of+two,+and+each+eight-connected+neighbor+has+a+bond+of+one.&source=bl&ots=LJ5C_5-wFe&sig=qGjXNMpKBhK4xNT49wtN4I_G754&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikj7_Vh7LaAhUN448KHerzBVoQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false